# How to connect ios application to raspberry pi (app code)?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

[image]

This is the interface made by me, i am totally new to iOS development but was able to make this much for my final year project, now i want to connect these switches to the raspberry pi, i need the code for the same and steps for the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but here is not a free code shop. You need to come up with something that you have tried yourself first and then people can step in and help you with the problems you demonstrate in your questions

Comment: Use bluetooth. Connect the phone to the rpi via bluetooth and send the signals over bluetooth. Write a python script to actually process the signals and turn the lights on.

Comment: @Abhishek Tyagi - any success on this ? I would also be interested in same.

Answer (score 1):

1. connect your pie to a Wireless Router/ switch connected to a wireless network/ etc..
2. Make a server from your pie: install apache, php and MySQL (MySql is optional if you need to store data on the pie)
3. Connect your iOS device running your App to the same wireless network
4. Communicate with your server (the pie) from your app using http requests.

Should be an easy task.
Good luck